# XML dataset in Crystal Reports

Tags: xml, crystal-reports, infopath

I am trying to print a report from within an InfoPath template.  So my dataset is an XML DOM that I will load into the Crystal Report at runtime.
But how do I define the dataset off which the Crystal Report is developed?
Crystal Reports has a great tool to build a dataset from an SQL database.  Is there something similar for XML schema that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right now i don't have crystal reports installed on my machine but if i remember correctly you can select as the source of your report an xml file.

i believe that you can also select the xsd with the data definition for your xml file.

in my case, since i was working with a dataset i would run my application and save the xml representation of the dataset with dataset.writexml(true) so that i would end up with an xml file that include the data definition

Answer (score 0):

I see the ability to pick XML in articles about CR on the web, but I don't have it available on mine.  Could this be because I am using the CR that is bundled with Visual Studio 2008?